# Listview with five elements and element in centre expanded (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Hey I am seeking help in implementing the above UI it is a horizontal listview with two elements in left and right the unique thing is that the center element is expanded compare to it's other nearby widget. Is there any way to implement above.

Desired Output UI

[image]

Comment: You can use page view builder.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you;ve tried so far?